# Merge two accounts does not work out

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

So, I am having a *few accounts*.

A while ago I registered one account via email. After that I started *authentications via Google* for like five other *Stack Exchange accounts*. When I try to merge them using the *contact formular* I do not receive a second email.

Is there a way to merge accounts where I used the Google authentication and my Stack Overflow account (which is my main account)?

Comment: How long has it been since you sent the merge request?

Comment: ~30 minutes. I receive the first mail within seconds tho, that's why I am wondering.

Comment: We merge accounts manually... you have to wait for an actual person to handle your request... and it's a holiday.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry! So I guess this can wait until next year :D happy holidays! :)

Comment: Sure :) sorry about the delay. 